# NET USE "The local device name is already in use"

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, net-use

I'm trying to map two drives from a W2003-Server from Win7 with the following batch-file:

```
net use m: /delete
net use u: /delete
net use m: \\{IP}\srvE /user:{sameIP}\Administrator {pswd}/persistent:yes
net use u: \\{same IP}\DATEN /user:{sameIP}\Administrator {pswd}/persistent:yes
```

The batch executes w/o errors and both drives are visible in eplorer afterwards and clicking on M opens the drive and everything is fine. But when clicking on U: I get an error "Microsoft Windows Network: local device name already in use".

I used a different drive letter before, have also done `net use * /delete`before and also deleted the registry-key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2` as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/240383/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-the-local-device-name-is-already-in-use) - but am still struggling with that issue. (Also logged off, rebooted etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, silly me - I found the answer while checking what I was about to write - but maybe it helps someone else, so I'm sharing it here: although "Administrator" suggests that I was able to do what I wanted, I was not: I had no permissions on that share. 
And the funny thing is, that after fixing the permissions, I am even able to access that share as N:\ and U:\ simultaneously - there is great logic behind "device name in use"! (**not**)... ;)